# Does ns2 has capability to implement store-carry-forward mechanism? If it has how to do that?

Tags: networking, wireless, ns2, adhoc, ad-hoc-network

I don't know ns 2 has capability to do this but I want to implement store-carry-forward mechanism in ns 2. However, I don't know where to start. Also I don't know what its steps. What protocols this mechanism uses? Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: DTN: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe5IYQe7MXM → Text: `DTN is a set of protocols that act together to enable a standardized method of performing store-carry-and-forward communications` .  DTN files :   http://www.netlab.tkk.fi/tutkimus/dtn/ns/ . Patch: `dtn_ns235.patch.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOXJlU0hPa3dGdHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you give more detail? what happens in that video ? why the nodes are not moving? What do that person to run that project? how combined that patch with ns 2? I mean I wonder the steps to do that project

Comment: Nodes not moving : In the real world radio towers and other stationary equipment is not moving : Stationary computers etc. .... All ~2500 simulations https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWUxzQ09uclA4TjQ/view?usp=sharing ... Basic examples https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript1.html

Comment: Well, if I gained moving to network as manets, does this approach work?

Comment: Manet: Give it a try, here are the  "Manet simulation examples" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbTdyQjRrR1U5ZTA/view?usp=sharing → →

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ns2 + DTN**

If you have other ns2 builds / installs : Rename the executable´s `ns` to a new name → `ns-orig`, 'ns-app-name', etc. And remove any ns2 *PATH text from .bashrc .

Build ns2 + DTN

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
zcat dtn_ns235.patch.gz | patch -p0
./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
```

Simulation : Copy an example (from ns2dtn_campaign/) to ns-allinone-2.35/, and run `./simulate_dtn.sh`. The location is important as this path is used : `../ns-allinone-2.35/dei80211mr-1.1.4/src/.libs/libdei80211mr.so`

Example, simulation files (and one empty folder) to be copied : { bundle-test-large-scen.tcl, create-traffic-file.tcl, scen_n40_pt2_ms20_t5000_x2000_y2000, simulate_dtn.sh, Run1/ }.

- Please note that the simulation time is an hour (or more).
- Watch the trace file qtrace.tr : Will very slowly increase to ~9MB.

Result : ns-allinone-2.35/Run1/{ bundle_delays.tr, qtrace.tr,   receipt_delays.tr }. The files can be used with Xgraph.